# Algolia instantsearch.js Minified exception occurred; invariant

Tags: algolia

I'm getting an error from instantsearch.js that doesn't make any sense to me. The error is:

Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.

I've created a fiddle with the code in question:

https://jsfiddle.net/qkqzgsv9/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div type="text" id="search-box" class="form-control"></div>
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Starts</th>
                    <th>Duration</th>
                    <th>Room</th>
                    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="hits-container">
            </tbody>
</table>
<div id="pagination-container"></div>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
  var search = instantsearch({
    appId: '5V0BUFDX8J',
    apiKey: 'a25692c12853aea7a77c5a7125498512',
    indexName: 'C86FE050-6C48-11E5-84AA-BA5F164D0BA4_events',
    urlSync: { useHash: true }
  });

search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
    container: '#search-box',
    autofocus: true,
    placeholder: 'Search for events by keyword, description, or event number.'
  })
);

 search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.hits({
      container: '#hits-container',
      templates: {
        empty: 'No events found',
        item: '<tr><td><a href="{{view_uri}}">{{event_number}}</a></td><td><a href="{{view_uri}}" target="_new">{{name}}</a></td><td>{{startdaypart_name}}</td><td>{{duration_name}}</td><td>{{room_name}}</td><td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{description}}"></span></td></tr>'
      },
    })
  );

  search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.pagination({
      container: '#pagination-container'
    })
  );

  search.start();
```

It happens in both Safari and Chrome. And I'm not even using the minified version of instantsearch.js. Any idea what's causing it?

Comment: So far I’ve discovered that it doesn’t like the HTML tags in the hits widget. If I remove all of them and just have the variables then I don’t get that error, which of course doesn’t work for me.

Comment: I tried replacing the template with a function, but get the same error: https://jsfiddle.net/cc57cLjn/4/

Comment: So it turns out it's just the table tags causing grief. If I wrap in divs then it doesn't crap out. Obviously its possible to simulate a table with div tags, but I'd rather not. Here's a working fiddle with the tags: https://jsfiddle.net/c6v7jvyd/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky bug and it is generated becauses this widget uses React internally.

The widget tries to render a div that will contain your template. But this is incorrect because your template contains td's which can't be rendered in div's, so the browser tries to fix that. This leads to React throwing an invariant violation error because the DOM is not what it expected. And finally you can see this specific error because React is minified in the build.

The fix would be to not use td's or wait for this issue https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/707 to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I've decided to just skip using instantsearch.js. It seems like it might be a bit early (buggy) and so I've decided to just whip up my own interface using AngularJS. I love all the little widgets, but it's really not that hard to create those.